# LSTMs - Carousel of Error

Tags: rnn

Is there any other materials that derives the LSTM back propagation and carousel of error except the original paper? (I could not understand it, sorry).

I tried deriving and got stuck, and asked the following question: [LSTMs - Data Science Stack Exchange question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19614/need-help-understanding-lstms-backpropagation-and-carousel-of-error), however, it doesn't seems that there are much people interested in hand derivation of LSTMs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One tool that may be helpful is [Aiden Gomez's](https://blog.aidangomez.ca/2016/04/17/Backpropogating-an-LSTM-A-Numerical-Example/) blog post. Its strength lies primarily in the fact that he runs through a toy/numerical example, which when paired with the [original paper/thesis](http://www.felixgers.de/papers/phd.pdf) , serves as a great foundational tool.

I did take a look at the [site you mentioned](http://arunmallya.github.io/writeups/nn/lstm/index.html#/) in your other question, it's actually an excellent resource. I'll hop on over and try and clarify what I can for you when I get a chance. It looks like you've misunderstood/overlooked notation which can happen since there are so many components involved.

It may also be worth taking a look at [some code](https://github.com/llSourcell/LSTM_Networks). Siraj Raval has a great video on LSTMs and includes the code in the link I've included. No libraries. I wouldn't dive too deep, but it's a great way to see the inner workings of the network.

As far as the CEC goes, there is a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/34piyi/why_can_constant_error_carousels_cecs_prevent/). If you're looking for a more rigorous handling of this topic you can either reference the original paper or often cited paper: [On the Difficulty of Training Recurrent Neural Networks](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.421.8930&rep=rep1&type=pdf).